# High-density RSS reader widget

Tags: app-widgets, rss

I've been trying to find a good RSS widget that maximizes the number of entries that will fit in 4x2 or 4x4, especially for titles or sites with short entries like headlines.

Any good ones out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TalkAndroid.com has this list of the top 5 RSS readers for andoid [here](http://www.talkandroid.com/8805-top-5-android-rss-readers/).

1. gReader (3rd party app requires your google credentials)
2. FeedR (costs 1.99)
3. FastReader (3rd party app requires your google credentials)
4. FeedSquares (3rd party app requires your google credentials)
5. NewsRob (3rd party app requires your google credentials)

Comment: Went with Feedr. Exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [Complete RSS](http://www.appbrain.com/app/complete-rss-widget/com.bai.rss) widget looks like it can get pretty dense. And, the app page says they'll eventually support custom font sizes, which means you could make it denser. The widget isn't free though, about $1.25 (US).
[image]